# db.Database.SqlQuery<>().ToPagedList()

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, pagedlist

When I use :

```
var result = db.votes.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

result get [pageSize] rows from database with good performance Not send to the database “select * from table”

But when I use:

> `var q2 = SELECT *  FROM [dbname].[dbo].[v1] ";`
>
> `var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<ISMS>(q2).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);`

result catch all rows from database in memory then convert it to pagedlist and
it`s very slow because (send query to the database is ‘select * from table’)

I monitor all with sqlServer profiler.

**However I want to use db.Database.SqlQuery for many reasons with good performance What I do ?**

My tests :

1.`var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<ISMS>(q2).AsQueryable().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);`

it also send ‘select * from table’ to database

2.

```
var q = string.Format("SELECT *  FROM [dbname].[dbo].[{0}] " +
    "ORDER BY id " +
    "OFFSET  {1} ROWS " +
    "FETCH NEXT {2} ROWS ONLY ", tablename , 20 * (page - 1), 20);
```

But I can’t use @Html.PagedListPager in view when I use above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PagedList` works best when you pass it an `IQueryable`, since it will know how to generate the query it needs to send to the database based on your page and pagesize.

using SqlQuery means you are executing against the database yourself and then passing the results (which are already in memory) to `PagedList`.

If you are interested in using SqlQuery, you'll need to handle pagination yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should select only the required rows from the database.

For eg:

`WITH Orderedtable AS
(
    SELECT something
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY something) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM table
)

SELECT * 
FROM orderedtable
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000`

Where 1000 is the starting record count and 2000 is ending record count.